How to add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in the Homer config file?
I want to use the Proxmox custom service of Homer to display some informations about them. Here's my config:
- name: "Proxmox - <NAME>"
  logo: "assets/tools/proxmox.png"
  url: "https://X.X.X.X:8006"
  type: "Proxmox"
  target: "_blank"
  node: "<node-name>"
  warning_value: 50
  danger_value: 80
  hide_decimals: true
  hide: ["vms","lxcs","disks"]
  small_font_on_small_screen: true
  small_font_on_desktop: true
  api_token: "PVEAPIToken=<API-TOKEN>

I get an "Error loading info" message and when I check the console it tells me that the CORS header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is missing.
Does anyone know how to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header value in the Homer config file?

You need to configure your Proxmox server to allow requests from the domain where Homer is hosted. Unfortunately, Proxmox doesn’t natively support adding CORS headers, so you might need a workaround.

There is no way to modify the config file of Homer to specify a CORS headers value ?
